# Magento 2 change text from region to county

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal, shipping-address, i18n

Magento 2 How to change the text from "region" to the "county" on the checkout Paypal page.
Need change text from -

Please check the shipping address information "**region**" is required. Enter and try again.

to

Please check the shipping address information "**county**" is required. Enter and try again.

Please refer to screenshot -
[image]

we already override en_US.csv and change the text from "region" to "county" but still, "region" is showing instead of "county"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the whole text on you translation file, something like this should wokr :)

Please check the shipping address information ""region"" is required. Enter and try again., Please check the shipping address information ""county"" is required. Enter and try again.

Comment: No it's not  working